# C++ how to overload operators for member variables

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, std-function

If I have a struct:

```
typedef struct Foo
{
    std::function<bool()> func;
}Foo;
```

and I have a void function

```
void bar(){std::cout << "hey";}
```

and I want to be able to do this:

```
Foo f;
f.func = bar // f.func == func(){std::cout << "hey"; return true;}
```

Comment: No need for that `typedef struct X {} X` nonsense in C++. Just write `struct X {}`

Comment: If you google *C++ overload operators for member variables* you will get your answer. You should do some work yourself and only if after due diligence you are still stumped, ask here.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing is that the function type for `void bar() {}`  is `void()` and not `bool()`, so func should be:

```
std::function<void()> func;
```

Second thing: it is unclear what "C++ how to overload operators for member variables" means. If you want to make your code compile then the above change is sufficient. The operator you can overload is `void operator()() { func(); }` if you want to call `f();`.

If you want to keep `bool()` function type and still be able to call `void()` function then you could use a lambda, which would call `bar` and return true:

```
f.func = [](){ bar(); return true;};
```

Comment: The comment on the last line suggests that he wants the assignment to result in `f.func` storing a modified version of `bar`, which, after doing what `bar` normally does, returns true.